# Javascript onsubmit() function not doing anything

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem with Javascript functions. My function won't work, I called it in a form with the onsubmit() call but nothing happens.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 window.provera = function(){
  nizError = new Array();

  var ime = $("#imeReg").val();
   var reIme = /^[A-Z][a-z]{2,9}$/;

   var prezime = $("#prezimeReg").val();
   var rePrezime = /^[A-Z][a-z]{2,14}(\s[A-Z][a-z]{2,14})*$/;

   var username = $("#usernameReg").val();
   var reUsername = /^([A-Za-z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]*$/;

   var email = $("#emailReg").val();
  var reEmail =/^[\w]+[\.\_\w]*\@[\w]+([\.][\w]+)+$/;

   var password = $("#passwordReg").val();
   var rePassword = /^[\S]{5,50}$/;

  if(!reIme.test(ime)){
   nizError.push('Pogresno ste uneli ime');
  }else if(ime = ""){
   nizError.push('Ime je obavezno da se unese');
  }

  if(!rePrezime.test(prezime)){
   nizError.push('Pogresno ste uneli prezime');
  }else if(prezime = ""){
   nizError.push('Prezime je obavezno da se unese');
  }

  if(!reUsername.test(username)){
   nizError.push('Pogresno ste uneli username');
  }else if(username = ""){
   nizError.push('Username je obavezno da se unese');
  }

  if(!reEmail.test(email)){
   nizError.push('email');
  }else if(email = ""){
   nizError.push('Email je obavezno da se unese');
  }

  if(!rePassword.test(password)){
   nizError.push('password');
  }else if(password = ""){
   nizError.push('Password je obavezno da se unese');
  }

  var ispis = "";

  if(nizError.length > 0){
   for(var i = 0; i < nizError.length; i++){
    ispis+= "<p>"+ nizError[i] +"</p>";
   }
   $("#result").html(ispis);
   return false;
  }
  return true;
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableLogin">
   <form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="provera()">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <label>Ime</label>
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" id="imeReg" name="imeReg" class="typeText"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <label>Prezime</label>
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" id="prezimeReg" name="prezimeReg" class="typeText"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <label>Username</label>
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" id="usernameReg" name="usernameReg" class="typeText"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <label>E-mail</label>
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" id="emailReg" name="emailReg" class="typeText"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <label>Password</label>
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type="password" id="passwordReg" name="passwordReg" class="typeText"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2">
      <input type="submit" value="Registruj se" id="btnSubReg" name="btnSubReg" class="buttonSub"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </form>
  </table>
```

When I leave # on action attribute nothing happens, but when I try to put some page like admin.php it goes to that page and again I can't validate my form.

I'm working on a website for my studies and I need to validate a form on the client side so if everything is okay it goes on to ther server side where I can again validate it with php and send to the database.

Comment: Add your `page.php` link for your action attribute. When your event handler (`provera`) for `onsubmit` is invoked, call `event.preventDefault` if the client-side validation fails. `preventDefault` will prevent the submit/page navigation from occurring.

Comment: `bob+something@example.com` is a valid email address but this form prevents that from being used.

Comment: Try linking in with `$('form').submit(function() { ... })` and include your function there to be sure it runs on submit. This is a more concise way of linking it in than this method of shoving it into `window` first. It's probable you're using the function before its defined with your approach.

Comment: It's also conventional to just say `nizError = [ ]` instead of the explicit and much more verbose `new Array()`.

Comment: Thank you on the tips @tadman but it wont work again

Comment: A) Check for JavaScript errors in your browser console. B) Create a more minimal test example that focuses on hooking in to the `submit()` handler.

Comment: Or maybe i can handle this with ajax. If validation is okay i send it to page.php and if not it return me exception with status code?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
   <input type="submit" value="Registruj se" 
     id="btnSubReg" name="btnSubReg" 
     class="buttonSub"/>
```

Use this:

```
    <input type="button" value="Registruj se" 
   id="btnSubReg" onclick="provera()" name="btnSubReg" 
    class="buttonSub"/>
```

And in your javascript add at the end if everything is valid this:

```
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

And add in "action" your php file path.

Comment: I done everything as you said and again nothing. It should show me text error from nizGreske because I leave everything in form empty, but nothing happens

Comment: This code is using jQuery so `$('#myform').submit()` should suffice.

Comment: You should give your form an id for example id="register"

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the OnSubmit() function

`<td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Registruj se" id="btnSubReg" name="btnSubReg" class="buttonSub" onsubmit="return upload(this)"/>
</td>`